# MediaWiki - rename page - "Move" tab not shown

Tags: mediawiki

I suspect this is a simple/silly/trivial problem - but I've spent ages without finding a solution.

I have a vanilla MediaWiki instance - a few months old - on an Ubuntu server recently upgraded to 14.04.  There is a single "user" - this user is in the "administrator" and "bureaucrat" groups when I look at the "User rights management" special page.

I need to rename some pages... I understand, from the FAQ, that I need to use the "Move" tab - and know that this tab is only shown for logged-in users. (The wiki is configured not to require users to be logged in to do edits.... I don't really need/want any access control.)

Even when logged in, I don't see a "Move" tab... Please can someone give me a hint - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What skin are you using? The "Move" action might be hidden in the auto-collapsing tabs of Vector. If everything fails, you can still append `?action=move` to the URL

Comment: I'm sure that using an Ubuntu server has nothing to do with this.

Comment: For the page http://mywiki/index.php/Wrongname I constructed http://mywiki/index.php/Wrongname?action=move and got "No such action: The action specified by the URL is invalid. You might have mistyped the URL ... might also indicate a bug..."  (BTW - I agree - Ubuntu is not likely the cause of my problem.)  I imagine I'm using the default skin - how do I tell?

Comment: I get the same error with http://mywiki/index.php?title=Wrongname&action=move - where http://mywiki/index.php?title=Wrongname&action=edit works fine to edit the page.

Comment: Sorry, I did confuse that with the [API action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Move). You can use the `Special:MovePage` special page instead.

Comment: Hmmm - http://mywiki/index.php/Special:MovePage?target=Wrongname does the job... so... I guess, it isn't a permissions problem.  I'd still like to know how to enable the "Move" tab - entering URLs directly isn't very user friendly. :)

Comment: Again, which skin are you using? In Vector, the move [tab](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Navigation#Page_Tabs) is likely collapsed. (See [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_page_tabs.png))

Comment: Damn, that was *VERY* stupid on my part!  I was looking for a tab - as the FAQ suggests - I completely overlooked the drop-down menu! Your link above solved my problem.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Vector skin, the <kbd>Move</kbd> [tab](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Navigation#Page_Tabs) is by default collapsed into a <kbd>More</kbd> tab. Depending on the version of your installation, that might only be an easy-to-overlook triangle:

`^^^^`